# Parsing the XML file has got error

Tags: java, android, domparser

Does anyone help find the problem why no xml file is not parsing with the following code.... the xml format can be seen [here](http://www.mobilenations.com/rss/mb.xml).

I tried to test line by line using log.i("your string goes here", xml); function but unable to see the execution of code when loop starts....

I have used to Splash activity in which AsyncTask() function is executed in the background and then ListActivity is used to display all the DOMParser activity output.... 
So anyone help me get out from this problem at all....
Thank you in advance

```
package com.wfwf.everestnewsapp.parser;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class DOMParser {

    private RSSFeed _feed = new RSSFeed();

    public RSSFeed parseXml(String xml) {

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(xml);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create required instances
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
            dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            // Parse the xml
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            // Get all <item> tags.
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            int length = nl.getLength();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Node currentNode = nl.item(i);
                RSSItem _item = new RSSItem();

                NodeList nchild = currentNode.getChildNodes();
                int clength = nchild.getLength();

                // Get the required elements from each Item
                // Ishwor changed the code j=0 and j= j+1
                for (int j = 0; j < clength; j = j + 1) {

                    Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);
                    String theString = null;


                    /*//ishwor changed as
                     if (thisNode != null && thisNode.getFirstChild() != null) {
                            theString = thisNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        }
                        */

                    String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();

                    //theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                    if(nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()!=null){
                    //if (theString != null) {
                        //String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();

                        if ("title".equals(nodeName)) {
                            // Node name is equals to 'title' so set the Node
                            // value to the Title in the RSSItem.
                            _item.setTitle(theString);
                        }

                        else if ("description".equals(nodeName)) {
                            _item.setDescription(theString);

                            // Parse the html description to get the image url
                            String html = theString;
                            org.jsoup.nodes.Document docHtml = Jsoup.parse(html);
                            Elements imgEle = docHtml.select("img");
                            _item.setImage(imgEle.attr("src"));
                        }

                        else if ("pubDate".equals(nodeName)) {

                            // We replace the plus and zero's in the date with
                            // empty string
                            String formatedDate = theString.replace(" +0000",
                                    "");
                            _item.setDate(formatedDate);
                        }

                    }
                }

                // add item to the list
                _feed.addItem(_item);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        // Return the final feed once all the Items are added to the RSSFeed
        // Object(_feed).
        return _feed;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share error log?

Answer (score 0):

```
   private Document getDocument(InputStream stream) {
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        if (stream != null) {
            doc = dBuilder.parse(stream);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        } else {
        }

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return doc;
}

private String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    String value = "";
    try {
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
                .getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nlList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nValue = nlList.item(i);
            if (nValue != null) {
                value = value + nValue.getNodeValue().trim();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return value;
}

public EntityBean parseDoLogin(String requestOutput) {
    EntityBean response = null;
    InputStream stream = (InputStream) new ByteArrayInputStream(
            requestOutput.getBytes());
    Document doc = getDocument(stream);
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("startTag");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);
        Element iElement = (Element) nNode;
        response = new EntityBean();
        String result = new String(getTagValue("result", iElement));
            response.setResult(result);

        String msg = new String(getTagValue("message", iElement));
        response.setMsg(msg);

    }

    return response;
}
```